# Sending(From) Mail configuration in django

Tags: django

I was configured email SMTP configurations in settings.py file as below

- EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
- EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
- EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
- EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'from mail'
- EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
- EMAIL_PORT = 587

Now its working fine but my problem is after deploying the project how can I change any parameter like from_mail/password by user input form...Simply I need to update/change email or password.

Comment: in settings.py you need to import credential from different file(like yml file ) so no-one can see credential. and add yml file in `.gitignore` so i not going to upload into repository. and if you want to take email and password from user, you just need to `send_mail` function to do that. `settings.py`'s credential not require there.

Answer (score 0):

You can always change the parameter at the function call of the django email function:

```
send_mail(
 'Subject here',
 'Here is the message.',
 'from@example.com',
 ['to@example.com'],
 fail_silently=False,
)
```

How to set the auth_user/auth_password is explained here:
[Django Docs Sending email](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/#send-mail)

Answer (score 0):

First, the Django documentation specifically says you shouldn't alter settings at runtime.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/#altering-settings-at-runtime

Fortunately, the `send_mail()` method allows the default `EMAIL_*` settings to overridden by using the `auth_user` and `auth_password` arguments.

```
send_mail(
 'Subject here',
 'Here is the message.',
 'from@example.com',
 ['to@example.com'],
 fail_silently=False,
 auth_user='new_user',
 auth_password='new_password',
)
```

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/#send-mail